# Figure out Ruby's strings

Tags: ruby

```
class Person
    def initialize(name)
        set_name(name)
    end
    def name
        @first_name + ' ' + @last_name
    end
    private
    def set_name(name)
        first_name, last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
        set_first_name(first_name)
        set_last_name(last_name)
    end
    def set_first_name(name)
        @first_name = name
    end
    def set_last_name(name)
        @last_name = name
    end
end
male_names = %w{George Emmanuel Bruno Connel  Cletus Samuel}
female_names = %w{Joy Stella Patience Rita Rachael Ruth Elizabeth}
puts "Please input your two names:"
    n = gets
    p = Person.new(n)
    full_name = n.scan(/\w+/)
    names = full_name.select do |name|
        if male_names.include?(name)
            nn=name
            na = "Mr "+nn
            puts "Welcome #{na}"
        elsif female_names.include?(name)
            na = "Ms "+name
            puts "Welcome #{na}"
        else puts "name not found!\nAre you sure you exist?"
        end
    end
```

If I enter `Connel Samuel` it will print:

> Welcome Mr Connel
>   Welcome Mr Samuel

I Just wanted it to print:

> Welcome Mr Connel Samuel.

Comment: I would consider better naming conventions for your variables as the code isn't so readable. Also, you failed to actually use the instance of your Person class (you're only scanning over the string input).

Answer (score 1):

The entire `Person` class here was a red herring. You didn't use it in the final print. You just used

```
n.scan(/\w+/)
```

And looked into the individual words you get from the input. There are two words - `Connel` and `Samuel`, each will get their own iteration. Hence `Welcome Mr Connel Welcome Mr Samuel`.

---

To fix it, you can check if the first or second name is in the male/female list and print the person's name:

```
if p.name.split.find { |name| male_names.include?(name) }
  puts "Welcome Mr #{p.name}"
elsif p.name.split.find { |name| female_names.include?(name) }
  puts "Welcome Ms #{p.name}"
else
  puts "name not found!\nAre you sure you exist?"
end
```

Comment: ndn; What should I use instead of 'n.scan(/\w+/)'?

Comment: Ok I get it now. I'm teaching myself ruby. Thanks for the tip

Comment: yeah it helped me a lot. twas what i was looking for.

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE, could you click the ✔ next to the votes up/down arrows then? xd

Comment: Ok. But I have a question I don't really know how to put it

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE, what do you mean?

Comment: I am teaching myself ruby, wanted to learn it more so set out to build a small questionnaire program. It's ruby console, it's there a way of doing something like a session process in ruby console with files?

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE, what do you mean by session console? You can use a REPL (irb/pry) if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm for now thinking of a questionnaire. It's in ruby console and with files.
E.g
* You started the program
* You register
* The questions start coming and you are answering.
* You stop the program maybe to go to work
* When you come back and open the program and signin again the questions don't start from the beginning but after the last one you answered:
...
Question 3 what's your favorite color
Question 4 Describe yourself a lil
...
 #you answered Question 3 and close the program. When you come back it starts from Question 4

Comment: @ConnelBLAZE, just ask questions with `puts`, get answers with `gets` and save to files if you want a load option. What does this have to do with the question here?